# Accessing Data from Within a List or Tuple and Cleaning it

Tags: python, list, sqlite, tuples

Here is a conceptual problem that I have been having regarding the cleaning of data and how to interact with lists and tuples that I'm not sure completely how to explain, but if I can get a fix for it, I can conceptually be better at using python.

Here it is: (using python 3 and sqlite3)

I have an SQLite Database with a date column which has text in it in the format of MM-DD-YY 24:00. when viewed in DB Browser the text looks fine. However, when using a fetchall() in Python the code prints the dates out in the format of 'MM-DD-YY\xa0'. I want to clean out the \xa0 from the code and I tried some code that is a combination of what I think I should do plus another post I read on here. This is the code:

```
 print(dates)
 output [('MM-DD-YY\xa0',), ('MM-DD-YY\xa0',)etc.blahblah] i just typed this in here 
 to show you guys the output 
 dates_clean = []
 for i in dates:
      clean = str(i).replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
      dates_clean.append(clean)
```

Now when I print dates_clean I get:

```
 ["('MM-DD-YY\xa0',)", "('MM-DD-YY\xa0',)"etc]
```

so now as you can see when i tried to clean it, it did what I wanted it to do but now the actual tuple that it was originally contained in has become part of the text itself and is contained inside another tuple. Therefore when I write this list back into SQLite using an UPDATE statement. all of the date values are contained inside a tuple.

It frustrates me because I have been facing issues such as this for a while, where I want to edit something inside of a list or a tuple and have the new value just replace the old one instead of keeping all of the characters that say it is a tuple and making them just text. Sorry if that is confusing like I said its hard for me to explain. I always end up making my data more dirty when trying to clean it up.

Any insights in how to efficiently clean data inside lists and tuples would be greatly appreciated. I think I am confused about the difference between accessing the tuple or accessing what is inside the tuple. It could also be helpful if you could suggest the name of the conceptual problem I'm dealing with so I can do more research on my own.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it “MM-DD-YY 24:00” or “MM-DD-YY 24:00”? I suspect it is the later, i.e. that the use of no-break space is intentional and you are *not* supposed to “clean it up”; instead, you should be printing it properly, i.e. *not* using the default `list.__str__`, which calls `repr` on the members.

Comment: Python 2 or 3? Unicode handling is the main change between them, so it matters rather a lot. Also, `sqlite3` or `apsw`?

Comment: In any case, please provide a complete code.

Comment: Sorry for not provide the complete code its sqlite3 python 3

Comment: By the way, sqlite does not have a special date-time type, but it does have date-time functions that expect timestamps in ISO8601 format and the python bindings have support for automatically converting these to and from `datetime.datetime` objects. So I would recommend you try to switch if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *garbling* the output by calling `str()` on the tuple, either implicitly when printing the whole array at once, or explicitly when trying to “clean” it.

See (python3):

```
>>> print("MM-DD-YY\xa024:00")
MM-DD-YY 24:00
```

but:

```
>>> print(("MM-DD-YY\xa024:00",))
('MM-DD-YY\xa024:00',)
```

This is because `tuple.__str__` calls `repr` on the content, escaping the non-ascii characters in the process.

However if you print the tuple elements as separate arguments, the result will be correct. So you want to replace the *printing* with something like:

```
for row in dates:
    print(*row)
```

The `*` expands the tuple to separate parameters. Since these are strings, they will be printed as is:

```
>>> row = ("MM-DD-YY\xa023:00", "MM-DD-YY\xa024:00")
>>> print(*row)
MM-DD-YY 23:00 MM-DD-YY 24:00
```

You can add separator if you wish

```
>>> print(*row, sep=', ')
MM-DD-YY 23:00, MM-DD-YY 24:00
```

... or you can format it:

```
>>> print('from {0} to {1}'.format(*row))
from MM-DD-YY 23:00 to MM-DD-YY 24:00
```

Here I am using the `*` again to expand the tuple to separate arguments and then simply `{0}` for zeroth member, `{1}` for first, `{2}` for second etc. (you can also use `{}` for next if you don't need to change the order, but giving the indices is clearer).

---

Ok, so now if you actually need to get rid of the non-breaking space anyway, replace is the right tool. You just need to apply it to each element of the tuple. There are two ways:

1. Explicit destructuring; applicable when the number of elements is fixed (should be; it is a row of known query):

   Given:

   ```
   >>> row = ('foo', 2, 5.5)
   ```

   you can destructure it and construct a new tuple:

   ```
   >>> (a, b, c) = row
   >>> (a.replace('o', '0'), b + 1, c * 2)
   ('f00', 3, 11.0)
   ```

   this lets you do different transformation on each column.
2. Mapping; applicable when you want to do the same transformation on all elements:

   Given:

   ```
   >>> row = ('foo', 'boo', 'zoo')
   ```

   you just wrap a generator comprehension in a `tuple` constructor:

   ```
   >>> tuple(x.replace('o', '0') for x in row)
   ('f00', 'b00', 'z00')
   ```

---

On a side-note, SQLite has some date and time functions and they expect the timestamps to be in strict IS8601 format, i.e. `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S` (optionally with `%z` at the end; using strftime format; in TR#35 format it is `YYYY-MM-ddTHH-mm-ss`(`xx`)).

Comment: Hi, this works great in terms of me being able to view it without any of the \xa0 characters in it. But I would like to use the dates in a text processing task in the future and I want to make sure if I use a regex to scan for a certain date I wont need to add the "\xa0" into the search. Therefore I need to ensure that that \xa0 is converted into a regular space. When I try to write the dates to another list to add back into SQL the \xa0 is still there. Any suggestions? You have been a great help so far hate to keep naggin ya.

Comment: nice I will try that today thanks for responding again!

Comment: Looks like it worked. I was able to create a new list that is perfectly formatted using the information you provided me

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `dates` is actually a list of tuples, with each tuple containing one string element. The `,` at the end of the date string is how you identify a single element tuple.

The `for` loop you have needs to work on each element within the tuples, instead of the tuples themselves. Something along the lines of:

```
for i in dates: 
     date = i[0] 
     clean = str(date).replace('\xa0', '') 
     dates_clean.append(date)
```

I am not sure this the best solution to your actual problem of manipulating data in the db, but should answer your question.

EDIT: Also, refer the Jan's reply about unicode strings and python 2 vs python 3.

Comment: Well, considering it is the `str()` that garbles the output in the first place, I think you shouldn't be calling it...

Comment: whoops thanks for the help but I think this one may need some changing because setting date = i[0] results in it just making the first date in the list repeat itself over and over again and it still is in the format that I explained originally.